# How do I get a member object to notify its container object?

Tags: c++, oop

I have 81 objects called Square located in a two-dimensional array in another object known as Puzzle. I want to make it so that when a certain function is triggered in an individual Square object, it triggers a function in its corresponding Puzzle object. How would you suggest going about it? Is it even possible?

Comment: You could pass a reference to the parent `Puzzle` to each of those objects and have them call the function. Or you could instead have the caller call a function of the `Puzzle` object, and maybe a grid position, so the `Puzzle` object can invoke the function on the right `Square`. Or you can get really fancy and use something like [`Boost.Signals`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/signals.html) to pass messages from the `Square` to any object that's subscribed to be notified.

Comment: For the second possible solution you posted: how would an object that inside another call a member function of the outside object? I do have a grid position recorded for each `Square` as I had seen a similar problem and attempted to glean a solution from it. However I did not manage to find one.

I honestly think your first solution is the best, but I'm trying to use as few pointers as possible, so I welcome other solutions. A guy can dream...

Comment: I think you misunderstood my second suggestion. Instead of having whatever function you have right now that calls a member function of `Square`, have that function call a member function of `Puzzle` instead. If the caller also passes in a grid position, the `Puzzle` can then call the member function of the correct `Square`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by implementing the "Observer Pattern". Your puzzle object will register for events in the Square objects. The Square objects notify the Puzzle when their state changes. The following link will help you figure out how to do all this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328365/Understanding-and-Implementing-Observer-Pattern-in

Comment: I've actually had that open for a bit, another friend recommended the same. However, the situation presented in the example code he's given doesn't quite fit with my current situation. In his code, the `Shop` object is the observer, which is a member of the `ASubject` class which the `DummyProduct` class inherits. In my system, I want the `Puzzle` class to be the observer and the `Square` class to be the subject, which complicates things, since `Puzzle` has-a Square, but `Square` doesn't have-a `Puzzle`.

Comment: The idea is to write the notify function in such a way that it takes parameters that helps you identify the Square Uniquely.

Square->addObserver(Puzzle)
in Square:
function Notify(){
   for(int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++){
      observers[i]->notify(this);
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that without modifying the `Square` and `Puzzle` classes is to encapsulate both the `Square` method call and the `Puzzle` trigger code in a function. A (somewhat contrived) example would be:

```
void GoUp(Square& sq, Puzzle& pz) {
   sq.GoUp();
   pz.NotifySquareGoUp(sq);
}
```

And now any code that needs to call `GoUp()` on the square object *and* notify the puzzle object need only to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean callback function?

you can store a pointer or reference to Puzzle in Square, when a certain function of Square is called, you can do things through pointer/reference.